# abstract class which calls a method of a subclass. How does it work?

Tags: java, interface, abstract

I read a code which is written in the book "Beginning Android Games" but I don't understand it completly. The entry point of the app is:

```
public class MrNomGame extends AndroidGame {
    public Screen getStartScreen() {
        return new LoadingScreen(this); 
    }
}
```

The class 'AndroidGame' which is extending here:

```
public abstract class AndroidGame extends Activity implements Game {
    AndroidFastRenderView renderView;
    Graphics graphics;
    Audio audio;
    Input input;
    FileIO fileIO;
    Screen screen;
    WakeLock wakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        boolean isLandscape = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        int frameBufferWidth = isLandscape ? 480 : 320;
        int frameBufferHeight = isLandscape ? 320 : 480;
        Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth,
                frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);

        float scaleX = (float) frameBufferWidth
                / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        float scaleY = (float) frameBufferHeight
                / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
        graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);
        fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(this);
        audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
        input = new AndroidInput(this, renderView, scaleX, scaleY);
        screen = getStartScreen();
        setContentView(renderView);

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "GLGame");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        wakeLock.acquire();
        screen.resume();
        renderView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        wakeLock.release();
        renderView.pause();
        screen.pause();

        if (isFinishing())
            screen.dispose();
    }

    public Input getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public FileIO getFileIO() {
        return fileIO;
    }

    public Graphics getGraphics() {
        return graphics;
    }

    public Audio getAudio() {
        return audio;
    }

    public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
        if (screen == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Screen must not be null");

        this.screen.pause();
        this.screen.dispose();
        screen.resume();
        screen.update(0);
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    public Screen getCurrentScreen() {
        return screen;
    }
}
```

You see the class extending 'Activity' by itself. That means that the app get into if you open the app on your mobile phone. In the onCreate method there is a method which is called 'getStartScreen()'. That is a method of the inferface 'Game' which is implemented. But the method 'getStartScreen()' isn't implemented in 'AndroidGame' therefore it is an abstract class. The method 'getStartScreen()' is implemented in 'MrNomGame' as you remember. As I have mentioned already the method 'getStartScreen()' is called in the onCreate method. That is the point which is confusing me. A superclass calls a method from its subclass. How does it works? And what happens if there were two subclasses which extending 'AndroidGame'? For example:

```
public class MrNomGame2 extends AndroidGame {
    public Screen getStartScreen() {
        return new LoadingScreen(this); 
    }
}
```

Which 'getStartScreen()' method will be called? That one from MrNomGame or that from MrNomGame2?

At least the Game-interface:

```
public interface Game {
    public Input getInput();

    public FileIO getFileIO();

    public Graphics getGraphics();

    public Audio getAudio();

    public void setScreen(Screen screen);

    public Screen getCurrentScreen();

    public Screen getStartScreen();
}
```

I know that is much code. I hope you can help me. Thank you very much.

Peter

Comment: Can you show the Manifest as well?

Comment: This isn't really Android-specific. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: I don't know how I can insert code into a comment, but I think you want to know which activities are in the manifest. There is just the MrNomGame Class.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic conceptual question about OO coding.

When a class is extended and then instantiated, the result 
is a single class which combines 
the methods and attributes of both.  As long as the method is defined for the
superclass, the superclass may execute calls to the method, even though the code
for that method may be written only in the subclass.  In fact, different subclasses 
may define different implementations of the method, so that the instances of
the subclass behave differently in that regard although the same for methods in
the superclass.

There is no ambiguity in the two classes that you mention -- MrNomGame is instantiated
and calling its method will execute the one it defines, and likewise for MrNomGame2.

If you literally want to know "how it works", that gets a little more technical.
The methods in the classes are represented in a "jump table", meaning that, when a 
call is made to one of them, the address of the method is in this table
built at runtime.  So the compiler can prepare a call to a method through
the jump table, and the runtime can ensure that the correct address for the correct
method is in the jump table when it is executed.

Answer (score 1):

It is the `MrNomGame2` instance which will call the `getStartScreen()` method and not your `AndroidGame` class.  I am sure the `onCreate()` method will be invoked on the instance of `MrNomGame2` class and then while execution the run time needs to call `getStartScreen()` , then it calls the `getStartScreen()` implemented in the `MrNomGame2` class , it is implicitly `this.getStartScreen()`.

Try this sample :

```
interface A12 {
    void show();
}
abstract class B1 implements A12 {

   public void callShow() {
     show();
   }
}
class C extends B1 {

   @Override
   public void show() {
      System.out.println("You are in C");
  }

}
public class AbstractTester {
      public static void main(String[] args){
       C c = new C();
       c.callShow();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a good example and I unerstood it. Thank you.

But I can't transfer it to my example because there is no line like 'C c = new C()'. Where my classes will be instantiated? These classes are part of the start procedure of the app. It seems to be similar but I don't understand it completly.

Comment: Could it be that android instantiate the class MrNomGame in the background because it is described in the manifest? If I put MrNomGame2 in the manifest then it will work with MrNomGame2, too?